# Android Bluetooth permission not displayed, still descirbed as turned on

Tags: android, bluetooth, permissions, manifest

I have a problem with bluetooth permission. I've declared in the manifest following lines:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:label="BLUETOOTH" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

What is weird that in app settings instead of bluetooth I've got a right to add permission for Location and Storage. But ok, lets say android doesn't provide specific perms for bluetooth and these are the same as BT. Weird thing is that even when I don't give any permission to the app (not for memory, not for localization), by using following code:

```
  int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN);

        if(permissionCheck ==  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(this, "granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "not granted :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

I still get message that permission are granted. What the heck? Should I check specifically for a EXTERNAL_STORAGE and Location permissions? And why bluetooth isn't displayed in app permision configurations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of permissions in Android:

Dangerous permissions: These permissions are required to ask on run time if targetSdkVersion is 23 or above.

Normal Permissions: If you define these permissions in Manifest that is enough.

For more details check this link given below:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: Yep, found it already, still don't know why are there displayed permission to memory and localization if I didn't ask for them.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what you are saying. Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Sure, sorry If i'm not describing it clearly. In settings of device you can choose app tab, and find your app there. Then you can choose permissions and enable chosen one. I'm curious why Android is asking for access to memory and location if I've not expliticly added them in manifest.

Comment: Are you using Google Play Services in your App?

Comment: Nice catch! Still, main problem which was a reason behind the question occurs. After disabling screen connection with remote device based on bluetooth got suspended. Added all permissions to manifest, turned off saving battery for that app, got reactive stream of pings every second. Still, connection seems to stop (app is freezed?) randomly :(